# Wicket Apache get tomcat session setted time

Tags: java, wicket-6

I'm trying to send my user a message/popup when thier session almost expires. But the problem I have is that I have set the session time out time in my tomcat settings, but I can't find a way how to get the time left of my tomcat session. I only found way's to set/make it yourself, but that's what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [`HttpSession.getMaxInactiveInterval()`](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getMaxInactiveInterval())

To access the HttpSession you can use:

```
    ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest().getContainerRequest()).getSession();

    ((HttpServletRequest) RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getContainerRequest()).getSession();
```

Keep in mind that the session timer will reset once the user sends a request. So ajax functionality wouldn't make much sense. Additionally the session could also be invalidated before the inactive timer runs out (typically in a login/logout scenario).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But if I do this I will get 3600 and I have my session time out 30 mins in tomcat...

Comment: Never mind... Had a double in web.xml of my application and I also added one to my web.xml of tomcat.